# Using all parameters of a function? I'm confused

Tags: c++

```
DrawBorderBox(55, 20, 200, 50, 4, fontBlack, pDevice );

void Menu::DrawBorderBox( int x, int y, int w, int h, int thickness, D3DCOLOR Colour, LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice)
{
    //Top horiz line
    DrawFilledRect( x, y, w, thickness,  Colour, pDevice );
    //Left vertical line
    DrawFilledRect( x, y, thickness, h, Colour, pDevice );
    //right vertical line
    DrawFilledRect( (x + w), y, thickness, h, Colour, pDevice );
    //bottom horiz line
    DrawFilledRect( x, y + h, w+thickness, thickness, Colour, pDevice );
}

void Menu::DrawFilledRect(int x, int y, int w, int h, D3DCOLOR color, LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice)
{
    //We create our rectangle to draw on screen
    D3DRECT BarRect = { x, y, x + w, y + h }; 
    //We clear that portion of the screen and display our rectangle
    pDevice->Clear(1, &BarRect, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_TARGET, color, 0, 0);
}
```

The values entered into `DrawBorderBox` are used in `BarRect`, well the call to `DrawFilledRect` doesn't use all the parameters? So does `BarRect` assume `h`?

So I get (55,20) point 1 and (255,70) point 2? But this says it draws 1 line? I'm confused.

I think thickness is being used as h in BarRect??? I'm I correct?
Which means that it would actually overwrite 4 pixels down of the original square?

Comment: By convention, variable and function names should start with a lowercase letter, btw.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall There is no convention in C++

Comment: Or rather, there are hundreds of conventions.  Which one are you referring to?

Comment: The one that SO's syntax highlighter seems to follow, as camel-case words starting with a capital are highlighted differently, so they obviously should be a different type of "thing". I'm not trying to imply that there is one convention for C++—there's not, but there are conventions.

Answer (score 0):

BorderRect is drawing 4 rectangles which outline the rectangle specified by the two points (55,20) (255,70).  What seems wrong is that the endcaps on the 4 rectangles don't seem to line up properly.  There should be offsets on x, y, w and h to either draw all 4 rectangles inside the larger box, or they should be drawn slightly longer and outside the box.